# Use case after order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I was reading an sql book, one of questions is:

*Write a query against the Sales.Customers table that returns for each customer the customer ID and region. Sort the rows in the output by region, having NULL marks sort last (after non-NULL values).Note that the default sort behavior for NULL marks in T-SQL is to sort first (before non-NULL values).*

[image]

And the answer is :

```
SELECT custid, region
FROM Sales.Customers
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN region IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, region;
```

I can kind of get the idea but still confused, let's take the record with **custid = 9** for instance:
since custid 9 has a null region, in the case cstatement return 1, so the query is sth like:

```
ORDER BY 1, region
```

which is equivalent to:

```
ORDER BY custid, region  --because custid is the first column
```

so how come the custid 9 is not before custid 10(the second record in the output)? isn't that output needs  to order by custid first, so 9 is before 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so the query is sth like
>
> ```
> ORDER BY 1, region
> ```

No this is incorrect. The expression `CASE WHEN region IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is evaluated per-row; and the `1` is a value instead of column position. Column position inside `ORDER BY` can only specified only as a literal and not as an expression. So this:

```
custid    region
8         NULL
9         NULL
10        BC
42        BC
45        CA
```

Becomes:

```
custid    region    case...
8         NULL      1
9         NULL      1
10        BC        0
42        BC        0
45        CA        0
```

And the sorted results could be:

```
custid    region    case...
10        BC        0
42        BC        0
45        CA        0
8         NULL      1
9         NULL      1
```

Or:

```
custid region case...
42     BC     0
10     BC     0
45     CA     0
9      NULL   1
8      NULL   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is incorrect.  The `1` is simple a number, not a column reference.

The query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT custid, region
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             (CASE WHEN region IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as region_is_null
      FROM Sales.Customers c
     ) c
ORDER BY region_is_null, region;
```

This is an important distinction about numbers in the `ORDER BY`.  The expression:

```
ORDER BY 1
```

refers to the first column.  However,

```
ORDER BY 1 + 0
```

is simply a numeric expression that returns the constant `1` -- and will result in an error in SQL Server (which does not allow constants in `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN region IS NULL THEN
             1
           ELSE
             0
         END,
         region
```

is not equivalent to

```
ORDER BY 1,
         region
```

because in the second one the first column to sort by is always constant, whereas in the first it can change depending on the `CASE`.

And

```
ORDER BY 1,
         region
```

is also not equivalent to

```
ORDER BY custid,
         region
```

again in the first the `1` is constant but `custid` is variable.

What

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN region IS NULL THEN
             1
           ELSE
             0
         END,
         region
```

does is to "generate" a new column to sort by depending on the content of `region`. That new column gets `1` when `region` is null `0` otherwise. If you imagine this new column in the table it would look like

```
custid | region | new column
...
10     | BC     | 0
...
9      | NULL   | 1
...
```

Now if this gets sorted by the new column and the region the customer with ID `10` comes before the customer with ID `9` because the one with ID `10` has the lower value for the new column -- `0` against the `1` from the customer with the ID `9`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - in your case 0 will be comign first then 1 so you need to change the order of the value, or you can do desc order if you don't want to change the value

```
SELECT custid, region
FROM Sales.Customers
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN region IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, region
```

Comment: sorry, don't get your answer, if region is not null, then order bu custid first, which is obvious incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use CASE statement to create a calculate virtual column to mark the nulls as 0 and none nulls as 1 and then sort accordingly.

if you use 0 in the order by clause you will get an error because you don't have a column at position of 0, also if you reorder the selected columns the result will be the same.
so the output of case statement is not a position of column it's a calculated column.

```
customer_id        region      marker
not important      if null        0
```